# Internal microphone doesn't work

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I have this in pulse audio input tab
[Pulse audio screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrNvX.png)

And this in the audio settings
[Settings audio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGjzD.png)

I have this card sources:

```
Source #49
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor
    Description: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    Driver: PipeWire
    Sample Specification: s32le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 4294967295
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec

Source #50
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
    Description: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    Driver: PipeWire
    Sample Specification: s32le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 4294967295
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: n/a
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY
```

I have tried to modify /etc/pulse/default.pa file to look like this:

```
### Enable Echo/Noise-Cancellation
load-module module-echo-cancel source_name=echoCancel_source aec_method=webrtc source_master=alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
set-default-source echoCancel_source
```

But it's not working. Thanks for help in advance.